# How to synchronize values updated in java events

Tags: java, swing, mouselistener, jtabbedpane, actionevent

I have following code :

```
class A extends javax.swing.JFrame
{
   int tabbedPaneID=0;
   javax.swing.JTabbedPane tbbdPane;
//1
private void tabbedPaneClick(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {
      tabbedPaneID=tbbdPane.getUI().tabForCoordinate(tbbdPane, evt.getX(), evt.getY());
      if(domainTabbedPaneID>=0)
              jTbbdPnApp.setSelectedIndex(domainTabbedPaneID);
      else
              return;
      System.out.println(domainTabbedPaneID);
}

//2
private void buttonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) { 
        System.out.println(tabbedPaneID);        
 }}
```

and **buttonActionPerformed** is called after **tabbedPaneClick**.

The **tabbedPaneID**  within **tabbedPaneClick** varies from 1 to 5
but  within **buttonActionPerformed** the value retains -1 (sometimes it shows 3,4 etc, ).
i.e. On clicking tab 2(tabbedPaneClick) i find value 2 but on clicking a button(buttonActionPerformed) the value shown is -1 ?

The following modification fixes the issue:

```
//2
private void buttonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) { 
        tabbedPaneID=tbbdPane.getSelectedIndex();
        System.out.println(tabbedPaneID);        
}
```

But Is there a better way of synchronizing tabbedPaneID across these two functions (so that i can do away with multiple assignments) ? An simple explanation on the problem will be very useful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like the problem is clicked tab index detecting (-1) means wrong coordinates.

```
tabbedPaneID=tbbdPane.getUI().tabForCoordinate(tbbdPane, evt.getX(), evt.getY());
```

X and Y here should be in tabbedPane's coordinate space. Check `evt.getSource()` if the source is not the clicked tabbed pane you have to convert the X and Y to tabbedpane's coordinates

See SwingUtilities' method

```
public static Point convertPoint(Component source,int x, int y,Component destination)
```

pass there the tabbed pane and event source.